# How to return the number of values greater than X with multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I am seeking for a formula that returns the **counts the values greater than 20** after applying two criterias.

### I have a table with 3 fields:

Field A: 18, 18, 19, 19, 21, 21, 44, 55, 55, 56, 61, 61, 75, 76, 86

Field B: 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1

Field C: 5, 2, 14, 7, 38, 1, 100, 76, 32, 65, 83, 20, 17, 41, 88

### I have two criterias:

Criteria1: 18, 55, 61, 75, 86 (this is an array)

Criteria2: 1

### Steps:

Step 1 - Apply Criteria_1 to Field_A

Step 2 - Apply Criteria_2 to Field_B

Step 3 - Return number of values greater than 20

Regards, 
Elio Fernandes

Comment: What kind of criterion is 1? I don't understand how I can apply 1 to a number. Is it testing equality?

Comment: Robin, the 1st criteria is an array of values -> 18, 55, 61, 75, 86

Comment: But what do those numbers MEAN?

Comment: The criterias are like filters.  First, I have to apply criteria1 to FieldA, this means that I have to filter FieldA wtih these numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUM(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A15, {18,55,61,75,86}, 0)) * (B1:B15 = 1) * (C1:C15 > 20))
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

This uses the property that `TRUE` counts as 1 and `FALSE` counts as 0.